# what does python.exe take as arguments?

Tags: python, arguments

does it take the filename of the .py and then what?

Comment: Type `python -h` to see all the options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It takes any options for python.exe itself, then the name of the file (or command or module), then any arguments to be passed to your program.

If no file is specified, it puts you in interactive mode.

As indicated in the comments by Adam, type `python -h` to see the full list.

Answer (score 21):

Documentation [here.](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html)